# Pyspark: How to derive a new column's value based on another column if any of the rows with specific id contains null?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark

Imagine I have a table:

| id | Feature |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 1 | b |
| 1 | c |
| 1 | null |
| 2 | a |
| 2 | b |
| 2 | c |
| 3 | a |
| 3 | b |
| 3 | null |

Resulting table should be:

| id | Feature | Contains null |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | True |
| 1 | b | True |
| 1 | c | True |
| 1 | null | True |
| 2 | a | False |
| 2 | b | False |
| 2 | c | False |
| 3 | a | True |
| 3 | b | True |
| 3 | null | True |

Because id 1 and 3 has a row in Feature column with null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In pyspark, you need a window function:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window as W
w = W.partitionBy("id").orderBy("id")
df.withColumn("Contains_Null",F.max(F.col("Feature").isNull()).over(w)).show()
```

---

```
+---+-------+-------------+
| id|Feature|Contains_Null|
+---+-------+-------------+
|  1|      a|         true|
|  1|      b|         true|
|  1|      c|         true|
|  1|   null|         true|
|  2|      a|        false|
|  2|      b|        false|
|  2|      c|        false|
|  3|      a|         true|
|  3|      b|         true|
|  3|   null|         true|
+---+-------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you tagged ***pandas*** it is pretty straight forward:

```
df['Contains null'] = df.groupby('id')['Feature'].transform(lambda x: x.isna().any())
```

Output:

```
   id Feature  Contains null
0   1       a           True
1   1       b           True
2   1       c           True
3   1     NaN           True
4   2       a          False
5   2       b          False
6   2       c          False
7   3       a           True
8   3       b           True
9   3     NaN           True
```

Comment: I will have a look for the same functionality in pyspark